# Remove the ".." from the end of the title of a ListPreference

Tags: android, string, listpreference

My app has a settings tab which contains several ListPreference items.

Here's the problem: on those ListPreference, only the part with the text is clickable, not the whole row, which is absolutely not user friendly.

So what I found as a workaround was to fill the title with blank space. Here's an example of my ListPreference:

```
<ListPreference
            android:key="language"
            android:title="@string/user_interface_language"
            android:defaultValue="en"
            android:entries="@array/user_interface_language_array"
            android:entryValues="@array/user_interface_language_values"
            />
```

and the corresponding string on the `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="user_interface_language">User interface language\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020</string>
```

So with that th whole row is clickable, but the text of the Preference is the following:

```
User interface language..
```

I want to remove the ellipsize ( the ".." ) but I don't know how to do. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try setting ellipsize property to none?

Comment: yes, in both the string and the ListPreference. still not working